# ASP.Net MVC:How to debug razor code in cshtml file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

i set break point in razor code but i am not being able to debug the code.

here is the picture which clearly saying **break point will not currently hit**

so please tell me what option i need to turn on in VS2013 IDE.

[image]

Comment: perhaps you need to re-build. It's normally possible to do this. Or maybe your build config is not set to Debug

Comment: ...or your view isn't even used by any controller or custom code.

Comment: Or you execute the code in release mode, have to be debug

Answer (score 4):

- 1.close your cshtml file
- 2.Rebuild your Project
- 3.Reopen your cshtml file,now  it will be ok and you can debug your c#
  code

Comment: this is not working for me in VS 2022

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in **debug** mode

[image]